# No overload for method 'Add' take 3 arguments

Tags: c#

[Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRzCd.png)
[Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQoI3.png)
Im a beginner programmer and not sure what this error is.
I have tried assign the input from user to object attributes and store them in a list.

I am also trying to figure out on how to remove the object from list and also display all objects in that list.
Any help would be great

Comment: What is the error that you're getting and would you put your code here rather than in the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to sample code below.

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();

Car newcar = new Car();
newcar.Model = 2001;
newcar.Name = "Fiat";

carList.Add(newcar); // Add Method 1

carList.Add(new Car() { Model = 2002, Name = "Nissan" }); // Add Method 2

carList.Remove(newcar); // remove enter code here

class Car
{
     public int Model { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an Instance of your object.

```
Items.Add(new Item(aname, aquantityInStock, apriceEach));
```

Take a read at: [How to initialize objects by using an object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer)